# Iterate throw checkbox list, even if not checked, in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a table of items, and if the user selects an item I need to know how many units are assigned to this item. So I created a check box list coming back with the selected items ids and another one for units.

```
<td>{{$item->name}}</td>
<td>{{Form::checkbox('itemchks[]', $item->id)}}</td>
<td>{{Form::text('units[]','0')}}</td>
```

The problem is that, unless the user checks all items we get 2 different-size lists.
For ex, when choosing 3 items, and assigning them some units values, the itemchks come back with these ids

```
["4","15","23"]
```

but the units list returns

```
["15","0","18","0","0","0","0","0","20"]
```

so I can't know, exactly, each id and its correspondent units.

I'm using laravel 4.2

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of letting the browser set the key in your `units[]` array you could do that yourself using the `$item->id`:

```
<td>{{$item->name}}</td>
<td>{{Form::checkbox('itemchks[]', $item->id)}}</td>
<td>{{Form::text('units['.$item->id.']','0')}}</td>
```